# Buscar todos os elementos diferentes de uma coluna (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, data.frame

Desenvolvi essa parte com as funções aprendidas em sala de aula

```
#importando pandas
import pandas as pd
#criando o dataframe
base = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\lsilv\\Desktop\\acessos.csv')
#renomeei as colunas para ficar mais fácil de usar
base.columns = ['login', 'plain', 'ip', 'lip', 'mpid', 'tls', 'session']
```

como faço agora para exibir apenas os valores como no  exemplo abaixo :

```
'login' 'plain'   'IP'    'lip' 
-------------------------------
dadosx  dadosx     ip1    a;b;c     
dados1  dados2     ip1    a;c      
dados1  dados2     ip2    a         
dados1  dados2     ip3    a ;b       
dados1  dados2     ip4    a;b;c;d  
dados1  dados2     ip1    a;b    
dados1  dados2     ip4    a;b
dados1  dados2     ip9    a;b
dados1  dados2     ip7    a;b
```

/>resultado

```
   'IP'     
---------
   ip1        
   ip2         
   ip3        
   ip4    
   ip9
   ip7
```

ja separei a coluna que preciso com a função base.loc

```
base.loc[(base["ip"])]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usa `unique()` na coluna, `base["ip"].unique()`